# Добавление изображений в angular приложение

Tags: node.js, frontend, angular, backend

Хочу написать приложение альбом с использованием Angular.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать добавление и хранение фотографий, и где их хранить? Нужен ли для этого Backend в виде ASP.NET WebAPI (который я знаю) или, допустим, Node.js?

UPD: Возможно, кому-то понадобится, нашел [Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#3606f862-8281-48f1-b0f7-49a5f77da0e1), которое позволяет создавать альбомы, а в них загружать изображения размером до 10 Мб и видео до 200 Мб, с разным типом аутентификации.